# Q: Event Espresso 4 event template?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, duplicates

"Duplicate Event" button doesn't work for me.  I need to replicate event data for multiple events (dates).

Can create an event template in order to create multiple events with the exact same settings/data? If so, what's the process?

Context: this is for recurring events involving sporting equipment rental.
Use the link below to see.  Forward to May.  Note the event times on the 15th.  I essentially want the exact same events replicated from 15 May-15 October and I'd love to avoid manually inputting each event. For example, I'd like to create a template for the 11a-1p rental and create an event for each of the days within the aforementioned time period without editing every detail of the event roughly 180 times.  Same for each other event.  That's 8 different events (all identical) for roughly 180 days of the season.  That's a lot of manual data input. Feel me?

[Events Calendar](http://surfballard.com/seattle-stand-up-paddle-rentals-and-sales/online-rental/)

Comment: First question posted. Forgive me my ignorance to process/protocol, if any!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you edit your question and provide more detail?

Comment: Finally found some info on a Recurring Events feature for EE4.  I basically need to buy the Custom Template add-on and this Recurring Events Drop-down feature. Wish there was a simpler (cheaper) way to do this! Ah well.